# C++ Function that uses BinarySearch algorithm (.bin file)

Tags: c++, string, binaryfiles, binary-search

I've to make a function that checks if specific word exists in .bin file. I want to use Binary Search algorithm. Thing is, I've to read from .bin file, so I got confused (as there's no lines, right?). Function doesn't work for me. It says that 'specific word' (entered by user) doesn't exist, even though it does.
Any help would be nice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
const int buffer_size = 30;

void Create_Bin_File ()
{
ifstream fin ("example.txt");  
ofstream fout ("Binary.bin", ios::binary); 
const unsigned int RECORD_SIZE = 30; // was BUFFER_SIZE
char buffer[RECORD_SIZE] = {0}; // zero init buffer

while (fin.getline (buffer, RECORD_SIZE))
{
fout.write (buffer, RECORD_SIZE);
// refill buffer with zeroes for next time round
fill_n (buffer, RECORD_SIZE, 0);
}
fin.close ();
fout.close ();
}

void Binary_Search (const string& filename, string SearchVal)
{
ifstream file (filename.c_str(), ios::binary);
if (file.is_open())
{
    cout << "The file is opened"<< endl;
    cout << "\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "Error opening file"<< endl;
    cout << "\n";
    return; // no point continuing Binary_Search() if file failed to open!
}
const unsigned int RECORD_SIZE = 30; // was BUFFER_SIZE
char buffer[RECORD_SIZE] = {0}; // zero init buffer
int recordCount  =  0;
int recordWanted = -1;
while (file.read(buffer, RECORD_SIZE))
{
    if(SearchVal == buffer)
    {

        recordWanted = recordCount;
        // if this was just a naive search loop could bail out now...
    }
    cout << recordCount << " : " << buffer << "\n";

    // refill buffer with zeroes for next time round
    fill_n (buffer, RECORD_SIZE, 0);
    ++recordCount;
}

cout << "\n";
cout << "file contains " << recordCount << " records\n";
cout << "\n";
if (recordWanted == -1)

    cout << "record wanted could not be found\n";
else

    cout << "record wanted is at index " << recordWanted << " records\n";
cout << "\n";
} 




int main()
{

Create_Bin_File();  
string word;
cout << "Enter word, that you want to find in a file: " << endl;
cin >> word;

Binary_Search("Binary.bin", word);


return 0;
}
```

TASK:
"Write a program in C ++. If the program works with a file, you should not copy the entire content of the file in operative memory. File component means fixed-length record. 
H7. Write a program that puts all standard C ++ reserved words in an ordered table (Ordered table as far as i understood means that these words are in alphabetic order). Write a function, which, using binary search, checks if an input string (length 30) is a C ++ reserved word or not. Table should be made as direct access file. C ++ reserved program should read from a text file."

---

grek40 solution on BinarySearch function:

So I make the record function:

```
std::string GetRecord(std::ifstream& inFile, int pos)
{
char buffer[RECORD_SIZE];
// clear possible flags like EOF, before moving the read position
inFile.clear();
// set the file read position to the requested record position
inFile.seekg(pos * RECORD_SIZE, std::ios::beg);
inFile.read(buffer, RECORD_SIZE);
// note: automatic conversion from char[] to std::string
return buffer;
}
```

And Binary Search funtion: (Solved - WORKING!)

```
void Binary_Search (const string& filename, string SearchVal)
{
ifstream file (filename.c_str(), ios::binary);
if (file.is_open())
{
cout << "The file is opened"<< endl;
cout << "\n";
}
else
{
cout << "Error opening file"<< endl;
cout << "\n";
return; // no point continuing Binary_Search() if file failed to open!
}
int pos = 0;
int lowerLimit = 0;
int recordCount = 73; // Calculated before[I'll change this part, when I get      this function working]
                  // At this point, there's exactly 73 records in .bin file
 char buffer[RECORD_SIZE] = {0}; // zero init buffer (while loop will overwrite with record values)
 int upperLimit = recordCount;
 while ( (lowerLimit < upperLimit) ) // Searching as long as it doesn't find it
 {
    pos = (lowerLimit + upperLimit) / 2;
    std::string buffer = GetRecord(file, pos);

    if (buffer == SearchVal)
    {
        cout << "Found!";
        lowerLimit = 1; // For stopping (If found!)
        upperLimit = 0; // For stopping
    }
    else if (SearchVal > buffer)
    {
        lowerLimit = pos + 1;
    }
    else if (SearchVal < buffer)
    {
     upperLimit = pos;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Binary search has nothing to do with binary file. And what is a `word` in your binary file?

Comment: @Holt Binary Search is search algorithm. I'm just planning to use it on my binary file, that contains different string records. Word = searchVal (a string that is entered by user - a string that I'll try to find in my binary file)

Comment: If you want to use a binary search, you'd have to read the whole file prior to the search because you need a **sorted** collections in order to use it, so I don't see how you are going to use the above code. By the way, my question was *"What is a `word` **in your binary file**"*?

Comment: @Holt Basically, I've .bin file (it's alphabetically already sorted) which contains strings (one word every line). So I need this function to tell me, if there's actually such a word[record] (entered by user) on that .bin file. I hope you got the idea.

Comment: @MaartinshKalejsMaartinshh "as there's no lines, right?" - Yes, there are no lines, but the newline is marked in binary too. Like in a string: "cat\ndog\nhorse\n...", but written into a file in binary. Your problem is, that you are reading blocks with a length of 30. And if your word has not 29 characters precisely, then you will read several new lines ('\n') or no new lines at all. Try out cout-ing the buffer in every loop iteration, marking every entry, and you will see what's wrong.

Comment: The binary search algorithm implies interval halving. Does your file structure allow this?

Comment: Is there any reason to open the file in binary mode when it contains line-separated text? Hint: having a *.bin file extension is no valid reason to treat the file as binary.

Comment: @ZDF Updated whole code. Take a look, please.            grek40 Yes, I've to open file in binary, there's no way around it (I'm learing stuff). Lasoloz it seems okay..

Comment: Just to be clear: are you trying to perform [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) on a binary file [binary file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file)?

Comment: @ZDF That's correct.

Comment: Did you even read the links that ZDF provided? If you do it should become pretty clear that "binary search" and "binary file" are similar by name and thats about it. There is NOTHING that would encourage the use of binary search on binary files.

Comment: @MaartinshKalejsMaartinshh To look okay it's not enough sometimes. I would suggest to try and print out every character value in numeric value (like this for instance, after outputting the `recordCount`: `for (int i=0;i<RECORD_COUNT;++i) std::cout << int(buffer[i]) << ';';`). Secondly, I agree with others, (binary) files and binary search algorithm does not work so simply together.

Comment: @MaartinshKalejsMaartinshh Another thing: you don't need to work in  binary mode when you are implementing something and you need to debug and rethink a lot of things. It's far better to try your code with "simple text mode" and switch to binary mode only after everything works fine. If you have an IDE, you can also automatize this with macros making a difference between debug and release modes.

Comment: @Lasoloz I understand that, but that's what I've to do. It's kinda homework. I think it would be harder for me to test things on .txt file and then .bin, because text files has lines, but binary doesn't, so it would be different. I also did that for loop and got bunch of numbers. I'm not sure how can I fix this cause tho.

Comment: @MaartinshKalejsMaartinshh Yes, you must get numbers, since you are converting characters to numbers. You can output the buffer, and after that you can output the string content with [std::string::iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/begin/), so you can compare them. If you get different numbers in your comparision, then you get (possibly) wrong characters from your file.

Comment: @Lasoloz So, you want to say that my binary search function is okay from algorithmic view, but the way of reading file is incorrect? (Getting different values which causes function to fail?)

Comment: **1** You should talk to your teacher about this assignment and clarify it. You most likely did not understand the assignement. He, probably, asked you to read the words from a file, store them in an array, sort them and run a binary search algorithm over the sorted array. **2** _"because text files has lines"_ If the file is opened as a binary stream you still get "lines". **3** To make it work like you want, you will need records of equal sizes (or an additional indexes file) and you will need streams knowledge that I doubt you have.

Comment: @ZDF Well, the task was to copy .txt file content (which is already alpha sorted) into binary file using fixed length records. And then use a binary search to find a user entered word. Is there anything you could help me with? I'm more worried about that binary search function. :(

Comment: You should post the text as provided by your teacher, exactly. This way we might be able to help you.

Comment: @ZDF  "Write a program in C ++. If the program works with a file, you should not copy the entire content of the file in operative memory. File component means fixed-length record. 
Write a program that puts all standard C ++ reserved words in an ordered table (Ordered table as far as i understood means that these words are in alphabetic order). Write a function, which, using binary search, checks if an input string (length 30) is a C ++ reserved word or not. Table should be made as direct access file. C ++ reserved program should read from a text file."

Comment: You should move the text up, in your question, so others can see it,

Comment: Did you translate this task from a different language? It doesn't read like anything that should be given to a student of any level. *unless its some project management task, that aims to learn understanding difficult customer requirement* but I doubt that one.

Comment: A related question, that might help you in understanding and managing your direct access file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401176/working-with-direct-access-files-in-c

Comment: @grek40 Studying CS - first year. Translation might be little bit off, but yeah, I've problems with this task, that's why I'm seeking some extra information/help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you have a solution where you move all given words from the textfile to the binary file and you are able to find words in the binary file if they exist there.

I suppose you created your binary file with sorted records of equal length (30), where the text part of each record is zero-terminated.

Now, lets create a function that takes an opened binary file stream and a record position and returns the string at that record position:

```
std::string GetRecord(std::ifstream& inFile, int pos)
{
    char buffer[RECORD_SIZE];
    // clear possible flags like EOF, before moving the read position
    inFile.clear();
    // set the file read position to the requested record position
    inFile.seekg(pos * RECORD_SIZE, std::ios::beg);
    inFile.read(buffer, RECORD_SIZE);
    // note: automatic conversion from char[] to std::string
    return buffer;
}
```

For binary search, you should define an upper and lower limit for your search position. Note that the upper limit is `lastItemPosition + 1`, so you never actually access this position in zero based index.

```
int lowerLimit = 0;
int upperLimit = recordCount; // count when reading the lines in .txt
```

You need to search for a result as long as you didn't find it and `lowerLimit < upperLimit`.

Your next search word is at `position = (lowerLimit + upperLimit) / 2;`.

Compare the word to your search text. On equality, you are done.

If the word is less than the search text, your result position can be at **higher** indices than what you just looked at. So you need to adjust `lowerLimit = position + 1`

If the word is greater than the search text, your result position can be at **lower** indices than what you just looked at. `upperLimit = position`

You repeat the search with your adjusted upper and lower limits as described.

Comment: Text file is sorted already, so no need for any sorting functions or anything. I think everythings is acceptable except Binary Search function, I don't really see why it doesn't work, because it should (obviously I'm not seeing some major error there) Thanks for effort though. Means alot.

Comment: @MaartinshKalejsMaartinshh last time I checked (visual studio compiler), your function did work (in terms of finding the result) but the algorithm is not binary search. Gonna edit my answer a bit.

Comment: @MaartinshKalejsMaartinshh my answer now concentrates on the binary search problem.

Comment: I just edited my post. Can you take a look again. I kinda got lost with your idea in a half way, but I tried similar approach

Comment: @MaartinshKalejsMaartinshh In the code line after `pos = (lowerLimit + upperLimit) / 2;` you can call `std::string buffer = GetRecord(file, pos);` with `file` being the binary file variable like you created it in your original `Binary_Search` function. Also, be careful with the re-assignment of `upperLimit` and with the `while` condition. I was extra careful with the `+ 1` and `<` and my solution will not work for some corner cases if you do it differently.

Comment: Okay, I tried to write that function just like you said - step by step. I edited my post once more, so now you can check it. Still doesn't work. I guess I'm missing some little part of that function out.

Comment: @MaartinshKalejsMaartinshh Please specify what you mean by "Still doesn't work". You also said that about your last code which was working for me (just using wrong algorithm), so maybe your issue is completely unrelated to what others can read from your question.

Comment: Well, I enter a word, for instance: "and" (which is in my binary file). By the BinarySearch algorithm, it should say, that "and" exists in my binary file, but it doesn't say so. That's it, because when I go over BinarySearch algorithm - everything should be fine, but I still get wrong answer from my program. Maybe it's caused by trailing spaces between words in my binary file?

Comment: @MaartinshKalejsMaartinshh You have to learn using the debugger for this kind of question... or just output the strings with some visible delimiter characters like `cout << "#" << buffer << "#";`, so you can see if there is a space between the end of word and `#`

Comment: Yes, it was space problem. I changed the while loop condition in CreateBinary function and now everything works. If you have any suggestions/advice on code - let me know. I want to thank every single person on this topic, every comment was valuable. I think I got the big part of code done. I also will edit code if someone in future have similar problem!

Comment: @MaartinshKalejsMaartinshh that explains, why your first code was not working for you... it was somewhat working for me, so the whole question seemed a bit strange. For future questions, try to focus on one specific problem (code should work, but does not; instead of asking for binary search). Be sure to keep practicing, then you will see alot of things for yourself. For example, you have multiple `buffer` variables in your function, while one would be enough if you chose the right one.

Comment: @grek40 Great answer but shouldn't the value of the next position be set to (lowerLimit + upperLimit) / 2 + lowerLimit?

Comment: @ErikAnderson beware my definition: *"Note that the upper limit is `lastItemPosition + 1`, so you never actually access this position in zero based index"*. With an inclusive `upperLimit`, one would need to play with some +1 / -1 corrections, but even then not add `lowerLimit`.Your proposal would bring the following result for example: `lowerLimit=2` and `upperLimit=3`. `(2+3)/2+2 = 5/2+2 = 4`, which would be more than the `upperLimit`.